# How do I get a model from a Backbone.js collection by its id?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my app, everything I do with data is based on the primary key as the data is stored in the database. I would like to grab a model from a collection based on this key.

Using Collection.at() requires the array index, Collection.getByCid() requires the client ID that backbone randomly generates.

What is the best way to grab the model I want from the collection with the given id value? I figure the worst I could do would be to iterate over each item, .get('id'), and return that one.

Comment: Isn't the get method what you are looking for? http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-get

Comment: Thanks! I skimmed over .get() since I was assuming it was part of their attributes key/value store... If you answer the question I can award you the answer.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Take a look at the get method, it may be of some help :)

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-get

> **get** *collection.get(id)*
>   Get a model from a collection, specified by an id, a cid, or by passing in a model.

Comment: I'll save you a click. The entire documentation there is: Get a model from a collection, specified by an id, a cid, or by passing in a model.
var book = library.get(110);

Answer (score 7):

If your data requires you to use a different kind of key or a set that doesn't mesh well with `at()`, `getByCid()` or `get()`, there is also `where()`. Something like this might work:

```
window.lib = new Library;
window.lib.fetch([
    success: function(model, response) {
        console.log(window.lib.where({'BookID':488, 'Rev':2, 'Status':'Active'});
    }
});
```